# Is it possible to download signing key used by google play?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

As you know, after uploading an apk file to google play, you can choose to let Google signs your apk with another key, in order to prevent losing key file for an app. So, every time we upload an apk, it will be signed using this key. Now, this approach has a limitation, consider that you want to sign your apk with this key without uploading apk to google play each time.

So, the question is: Is it possible to download key file and sign my app locally? How? What will be the key password and alias password in this case?

Comment: I would be very surprised if Google Play would let you download their signing key, as it would probably be a security breach.  If you want to test your app locally, just do so using debug or production mode from your laptop.

Comment: Why it would be a breach? isn't this key unique to your account and application?

Comment: Why is it important to use the same signing key if you don't upload to google play?

Comment: Be cause I have multiple flavors for this app and I want to generate and sign them which only one of them will be uploaded to google play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to download the private key that Google generated to sign your app.

The options I see for your use case are:

- Create a new app on the Play Console for your new flavours, and ask to be signed with the same key as your other app. Even without publishing this app externally (e.g. keep it on a test track), Play would generate the APK which you could download immediately after.
- Delete your app, and recreate it but this time, give Play the key you want your app to be signed with instead of letting Google generate it. It is possible since a couple of weeks ago.

Hope that helps.